# How to get value outside the $promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I had strucked in making use of $promise value outside the api call but I am getting as undefined. Please help me how can I get the value outside .

```
getPeople($scope.selectedId).fetch({
          }).$promise.then(
              function (value) {
                  $scope.peopledata = value.data[0];
                  console.info($scope.peopledata); // here I can get data
              },
              function (err) {
              });
```

`console.info($scope.peopledata);` // but here I was getting undefined

how can I get data outside?

Comment: if you log `value.data` what are you getting

Comment: did you wait for the promise to resolve before you `console.log` outside of the promise (that's what promises are there for)?

Comment: In short, inside a promise you are geting $scope.peopledata, but outside you have still undefined? Do I understand it correctly?

Answer (score 2):

I think you got confused about what Promises are and how they work.

A statement following the `getPeople` call is executed immediately, while the promise may not be resolved yet (remember, it's asynchronous). So you are trying to display something on the console at a point where it wasn't initialized. The code order itself doesn't matter anymore when using asynchronous functions.

From what you have posted, your code works as expected. See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise